# Adding Vertical Braces to ggplot percent stacked grouped bargraph using ggbrace package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add some curly braces to my stacked bar graph where the braces correspond to certain categories the fill variables are in. In this case, I'm trying to add four curly braces to the last bar in the barchart, where one curly brace represents 4 fill variables, another represents 2, and a last one represents 1.
**Background:**
A proportion stacked bargraph of household type by age group. There are four bars, each representing a distinct age group. Each bar is filled with the 7 household type categories. I'd like to add curly braces to the last stacked bar to explain the three categories these 7 household types fall under.

I've tried using geom_brace() however I'm struggling both with trying to enter the x/y values myself and with trying to use it by inheriting data.

I used [geom_brace() from the ggbrace package](https://rdrr.io/github/Solatar/ggbrace/man/geom_brace.html) as other bracket/brace packages didn't do well with ggplot and/or creating vertical braces.

**I've tried using geom_brace() with inheriting data:**

```
ggplot(hhtype_by_agegroup_proptable, aes(fill=hh_type, y=percentage, x=as.factor(agegroup), label=label_percent_format(percentage)))+
    geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity", width=0.4)+ 
    scale_y_continuous(labels=axis_percent_format, n.breaks=10, minor_breaks=seq(0,1,0.05))+
    scale_x_discrete(labels=get_labels(BOSPersonHHinfoCOPY$agegroup))+
    scale_fill_manual(values=palette_households2, labels=get_labels(BOSPersonHHinfoCOPY$hh_type))+
    geom_brace(bending=0.01, mid=0.5, rotate=90, inherit.data=TRUE, inherit.aes = TRUE,         textORlabel="label", col="red")
```

This is what my visualization looks like:
[image: visualization with bending param=0.01]

This is what it looks like when I change the bending parameter to 1 and then to 5
[image: visualization with bending param=1]
[image: visualization with bending param=5]

The 'bend' parameter works strangely. I only see lines when I have the bend parameter defined. While it's supposed to change the bend in the curly brace it ends up just shortening the brace line, and no actual 'brace' is drawn, just lines. I also would like to have the braces only apply to the final bar, not all of the bars. How might I do this?

**I've tried using geom_brace() manually:**
I've also tried doing it manually, as I suspect the 'fill' aes might cause some issues. However, when I manually enter a 'y' value, the line also doesn't show up until I fill in 'bend' which causes similar issues as before, creating lines as long as the parameter entered for bend instead of creating curly braces.

This is my code for the manual method:

```
ggplot(hhtype_by_agegroup_proptable, aes(fill=hh_type, y=percentage, x=as.factor(agegroup), label=label_percent_format(percentage)))+
    geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity", width=0.4)+ 
    scale_y_continuous(labels=axis_percent_format, n.breaks=10, minor_breaks=seq(0,1,0.05))+
    scale_x_discrete(labels=get_labels(BOSPersonHHinfoCOPY$agegroup))+
    scale_fill_manual(values=palette_households2, labels=get_labels(BOSPersonHHinfoCOPY$hh_type))+
    geom_brace(rotate=90, aes(x=1.5, y=0.662), bend=0.07)
```

This is the result:
[image: manual data assignment result]

I think the manual route may be the easiest, however, I'm not sure why it's not working.

Might anyone have any advice? Thank you!

*** EDIT ***
For code reproducibility, dput(hhtype_by_agegroup_proptable) yields:

```
structure(list(agegroup = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), labels = c(`18 to 19` = 1, 
`20 to 24` = 2, `25 to 29` = 3, `30 to 34` = 4, `35 to 44` = 5, 
`45 to 54` = 6, `55 to 64` = 7, `65+` = 8)), hh_type = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), labels = c(`Spouse or unmarried partner` = 1, 
`Child or grandchild of householder` = 2, `Single parent` = 3, 
`Lives in other family household` = 4, `Lives with friends or roommates` = 5, 
`Live alone` = 6, `Lives in group quarters` = 7), class = "factor"), 
    N = c(159, 7926, 47, 781, 1353, 480, 21017, 3064, 15565, 
    319, 3245, 27156, 4308, 14704, 24706, 12272, 1906, 4395, 
    32721, 10704, 1655, 32957, 7400, 3389, 3766, 12499, 11340, 
    1308), total = c(31763, 31763, 31763, 31763, 31763, 31763, 
    31763, 68361, 68361, 68361, 68361, 68361, 68361, 68361, 88359, 
    88359, 88359, 88359, 88359, 88359, 88359, 72659, 72659, 72659, 
    72659, 72659, 72659, 72659), percentage = c(0.00500582438686522, 
    0.249535623209395, 0.00147970909548846, 0.024588357522904, 
    0.042596732046721, 0.015111922677329, 0.661681831061298, 
    0.0448208774008572, 0.227688301809511, 0.00466640335864016, 
    0.0474685858896154, 0.3972440426559, 0.0630183876771844, 
    0.215093401208291, 0.2796093210652, 0.138887945766702, 0.0215710906642221, 
    0.0497402641496622, 0.37031881302414, 0.121142158693512, 
    0.0187304066365622, 0.453584552498658, 0.101845607564101, 
    0.0466425356803699, 0.0518311564981627, 0.172022736343743, 
    0.156071512132014, 0.0180018992829519), lab = c("0.5%", "24.95%", 
    "0.15%", "2.46%", "4.26%", "1.51%", "66.17%", "4.48%", "22.77%", 
    "0.47%", "4.75%", "39.72%", "6.3%", "21.51%", "27.96%", "13.89%", 
    "2.16%", "4.97%", "37.03%", "12.11%", "1.87%", "45.36%", 
    "10.18%", "4.66%", "5.18%", "17.2%", "15.61%", "1.8%")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -28L), groups = structure(list(
    agegroup = structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4), labels = c(`18 to 19` = 1, 
    `20 to 24` = 2, `25 to 29` = 3, `30 to 34` = 4, `35 to 44` = 5, 
    `45 to 54` = 6, `55 to 64` = 7, `65+` = 8)), .rows = structure(list(
        1:7, 8:14, 15:21, 22:28), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE))
```

The table looks like this:
[Image of proportion table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQFWc.png)

Comment: Hi. Would you be able to add some data so we can replicate your plot to test and verify solutions? The output of `dput(hhtype_by_agegroup_proptable)` would make your question reproducible. Thanks.

Comment: Will add that now, thank you!